Multi-level xml in the DataSet and output to the dataGridView1 table
DataSet incorrectly outputs XML data to dataGridView1 due to the same names in the child tables.
here is my code...
 DataSet dataSet = new DataSet("Language");

 private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
     ofd.Filter = "XML|*.xml";
     if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
     {
         try
         {
             List<string> listTableName = new List<string>();
             XmlReader xmlFile = XmlReader.Create(ofd.FileName, new XmlReaderSettings());
             dataSet.ReadXml(xmlFile);

             for (int i = 0; i <= dataSet.Tables.Count - 1; i++)
                 if (dataSet.Tables[i].ChildRelations.Count != 0)
                     comboBox1.Items.Add(dataSet.Tables[i].TableName); 

             dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;
             xmlFile.Close();

         }

         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             Console.WriteLine(ex);
         }
     }
 }

 private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
         dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].DefaultView;
     else
         dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[comboBox1.Text].ChildRelations[0].ChildTable.DefaultView;
 }


here is the xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Language xmlns:dt="some-xml-namespace-here" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Name>English</Name>
  <Code>EN</Code>
  <Font>font_english</Font>
  <Reagents>
    <RecordReagent>
      <Key>Flour</Key>
      <Value>Flour</Value>
      <Unit>g</Unit>
    </RecordReagent>
    <RecordReagent>
      <Key>Milk</Key>
      <Value>Milk</Value>
      <Unit>ml</Unit>
    </RecordReagent>
  </Reagents>
  <Gases>
    <Record>
      <Key>Oxygen</Key>
      <Value>Oxygen</Value>
    </Record>
    <Record>
      <Key>CarbonDioxide</Key>
      <Value>Carbon Dioxide</Value>
    </Record>
    <Record>
      <Key>Nitrogen</Key>
      <Value>Nitrogen</Value>
    </Record>
  </Gases>
  <Actions>
    <Record>
      <Key>Reload</Key>
      <Value>Reload</Value>
    </Record>
        <Record>
      <Key>123124</Key>
      <Value>1323123</Value>
    </Record>
  </Actions>
  <ScreenSpaceToolTips />
</Language>

the problem is that the Gases and Actions table have the same Record table, and not their own. on Russian forums, I did not receive an answer on how to make it so that when choosing comboBox1 Gases, its Record table is selected and not the general one (while the code should be universal without specifying the table name)

https://i.imgur.com/5HF9GdD.png
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        

        if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].DefaultView;
        else
        { 

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()].ChildRelations[0].ChildTable.AsEnumerable().Where(o => o.Field<int?>(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()+ "_Id") == 0).AsDataView();

        }

    }


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?

Try following code using Xml Linq
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp10
{

    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            DataSet language = new DataSet("Language");

            DataTable dt = new DataTable("Reagents");
            language.Tables.Add(dt);
            dt.Columns.Add("Key", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Unit", typeof(string));

            foreach (XElement reagents in doc.Descendants("RecordReagent"))
            {
                string key = (string)reagents.Element("Key");
                string value = (string)reagents.Element("Value");
                string unit = (string)reagents.Element("Unit");
                dt.Rows.Add(new  { key, value, unit });
            }

            XElement gases = doc.Descendants("Gases").FirstOrDefault();

            dt = new DataTable("Gases");
            language.Tables.Add(dt);
            dt.Columns.Add("Key", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(string));

            foreach (XElement record in gases.Descendants("Record"))
            {
                string key = (string)record.Element("Key");
                string value = (string)record.Element("Value");
                dt.Rows.Add(new { key, value});
            }

            XElement actions = doc.Descendants("Actions").FirstOrDefault();

            dt = new DataTable("Actions");
            language.Tables.Add(dt);
            dt.Columns.Add("Key", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(string));

            foreach (XElement record in actions.Descendants("Record"))
            {
                string key = (string)record.Element("Key");
                string value = (string)record.Element("Value");
                dt.Rows.Add(new { key, value });
            }
        }
    }
}

Here is generic version of the code
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp10
{

    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            DataSet language = new DataSet("Language");

            XElement root = doc.Root;

            foreach(XElement element in root.Elements())
            {
                if(element.HasElements)
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    language.Tables.Add(dt);

                    foreach(XElement column in element.Elements().First().Elements())
                    {
                        dt.Columns.Add(column.Name.LocalName);
                    }
                    foreach(XElement child in element.Elements())
                    {
                        DataRow row = dt.Rows.Add();
                        foreach(XElement col in child.Elements())
                        {
                            string key = col.Name.LocalName;
                            string value = (string)col.Value;
                            row[key] = value;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


(while the code should be universal without specifying the table name )......... names of columns or other requests ...

I added a more generic version of the code.

aa understood... roughly speaking, you are creating 3 additional tables, I will only need to figure out how to output exactly the new table, and not the old one... and if the xml is going to be with 20 thousand lines, then it's just terrible... I thought it would be possible to somehow come up with something with invisible columns. Anyway, THANKS A LOT... You gave me something to think about (I don't know if you understood me). ...https://i.imgur.com/5HF9GdD.png

that's what I was looking for))
dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()].ChildRelations[0].ChildTable.AsEnumerable().Where(o => o.Field<int?>(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()+ "_Id") == 0).AsDataView();
